# Retrieve from many to many relationship. Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, information-retrieval

I'm trying to retrieve data from many to many relationship.I have two tables :

```
companies: [cid,name,origin]

vehicle_types: [id, type]
```

their pivot table: `companies_vehicle_types: companies_id,vehicle_types_id`
Relationship defined:
In Companies:

```
public function vehicle_types(){

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\vehicle_types');
}
```

In vehicle_types

```
public function companies(){

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\companies')->withTimestamps();
}
```

I want to retrieve companies where vehicle_types = specific type. How can i do that?
I tried doing following in my controller:

```
$vehicle_types=vehicle_types::all()->whereLoose('type','Bike');
foreach ($vehicle_types->companies as $vehicle_types) {
      $company[]=$vehicle_types->pivot->name;
}
return $company;
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. It throws error of `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$companies`

Comment: Override the second, third and fouth argument in the relation if you are not following laravel's convention. See the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the second, third and fouth argument in the relation if you are not following laravel's convention. See the documentation [Many to Many Relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

> Second argument determines the table name of the relationship's
>   joining table.  The third argument is the foreign key name of the
>   model on which you are defining the relationship, while the fourth
>   argument is the foreign key name of the model that you are joining to:

```
public function vehicle_types(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\vehicle_types', 'companies_vehicle_types', 'companies_id', 'vehicle_types_id');
}
```

Also, One $vehicle_type can have many companies, so:

```
$vehicle_types=vehicle_types::all()->whereLoose('type','Bike');
foreach ($vehicle_types as $vehicle_type) {
  foreach($vehicle_type->companies as $company)
    { 
      $company[]=$company->pivot->name;
    }
   endforeach
}
```

Again, I don't see `name` field in pivot table for this line to work:   `$company[]=$company->pivot->name;`

Comment: Is it maybe because $vehicle_types is returning collection instead of object?

Comment: @Anon oh yes.One vehicle_type can have many companies, so you have to loop the `$vehicle_types` first and then `$vehicle_type->companies`

Comment: It definitely solved earlier problem. But i unknowingly didn't followed the convention and wrote 'cid' instead of 'id' in table companies. Now it is throwing unknown column companies.id Is there any way to make it companies.cid or i will have to change the table structure?

Comment: @Anon if it is primar key, you can override this property  `protected $primaryKey = 'cid';`

Comment: I'm sorry but it is throwing following error now:
`Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::setAttribute(), called in C:\Users\Man'ish\Automobile\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php on line 2892 and defined`

Comment: @Anon  `setAttribute()` requires first argument as key and second as value.  you can see here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2884. with this line   `$company[]=$vehicle_types->pivot->name;` you have the value but not key, i don't see `name` field in your pivot table.

Comment: Sanzeeb Aryal sathi, updated question ek choti herdeu na. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41789718/array-returning-null-value-many-to-many-laravel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133774/discussion-between-sanzeeb-aryal-and-anon).